# Got CORS ERROR when try out API via Devportal and Publisher WSO2 AM 4.2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hi everyone i have a problem with WSO2 AM 4.2.

When i want to try out API via Devportal and Publisher, it always return "Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: CORS, Network Failure, URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS Request. But when i try to curl the API, it works fine. And i try to inspect, it gave me "Access to fetch at 'https://abcd.domain/dummyapi/1.0/users' from origin 'https://abde.domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. GET https://abcd.domain/dummyapi/1.0/users net::ERR_FAILED

I already try to config allow_origins = "https://abde.domain" on my deployment.toml and i use chrome as my browse. Did i miss some configuration on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new browser tab and navigate to `https://abcd.domain/dummyapi/1.0/users`. If this prompts to accept the certificate go ahead and accept it.

Then try to invoke the API through tryout portals in APIM and see whether it works.